# Até onde um erro de digitação é motivo para fechar uma pergunta?

Tags: debate, razões-fechamento

Não estou querendo vitimar a pergunta, ela apenas calhou em uma dúvida prévia que eu já tinha.

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/294637/64969) o AP fez uma atribuição de uma variável que não fora inicializada explicitamente por ele para uma outra variável. Ele leu as variáveis `n1` e `n2` e então, após decidir quem era a maior, faz `n1 <- maior`. Isso, para mim, consistiu de um erro de digitação, pois ele pensou em atribuir para `maior` o valor de `n1`, só que escreveu o contrário.

Mesmo sendo um erro de digitação, não sei se seria interessante fechá-la por esse motivo. Afinal, quem nunca esqueceu de inicializar uma variável, né? Mesmo sendo um erro de digitação, uma resposta que indicasse esse tipo de erro seria útil para os novatos na área. Se seria útil para alguém além do AP, então já vejo motivo para ela estar aqui (ou marcar como duplicata, não fui atrás de saber se já existe uma resposta). No próprio [como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) tem uma seção dedicada a tornar útil para outras pessoas, e em [no tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) cita que uma pergunta, se é de um problema específico de programação, então ela é bem-vinda aqui.

Então, para concluir, quanto devemos levar em consideração erros de digitação?

Comment: Lembrando que o motivo de fechamento não é apenas erro de digitação mas também "o problema não  pode ser reproduzido". Eu acho que esse motivo deve ser usado em perguntas antigas e que tinham apenas um erro relativamente trivial (não necessariamente problema de digitação). Ou se alguém nos comentários resolveu o problema do perguntador. Ou se o próprio perguntador encontrou a sua solução e deu essa respectiva informação nos comentários. Qualquer que seja o cenário o motivo deve ser usado se for um problema "bobo". Se teve respostas de outros usuários se calhar não deve fechar.

Comment: Eu admito que não procurei ainda entender o caso, mas adianto minha opinião, se o erro de digitação é por confusão do autor acho que tem que fechar, pode até comentar e responder, ainda sim fechar ... mas se é porque o autor não conhece a sintaxe de algo ou qual o procedimento e o erro de digitação foi uma tentativa hipotética do AP de executar algo então fica no limite do ON/OFF, que creio eu seja totalmente valido manter como aberta, principalmente dependendo do nivel de complexidade da sintaxe, algoritimo, condição. Todavia cada caso é um caso e infelizmente temos que analisar bem cada ...

Comment: ... O problema maior são os incapacitados na *"fila de analise"* votando sem ter capacidade e conhecimento técnico suficiente para tecnologias especificas e ainda por cima acreditam (e esbravejam) que estão *"praticando o bem"*.

Answer (score 6):

Se for fechada, mas a pergunta é positiva ela ficará no site. Não tem porque dar outra resposta além de dizer que errou ali. Não irá ajudar mais ninguém. As pessoas não verão esta pergunta e não inverter mais as variáveis porque leram aquilo. Então foge do objetivo do site que é ajudar as pessoas de forma geral. Se não fosse fechada por erro de digitação seria por duplicata já que teria trocentas perguntas iguais, onde a resposta é "você inverteu as variáveis".

Eu não acho que isto ensine algo para alguém, apenas alerta para aquele erro. Então é erro de digitação.

Nem tudo é. Mas muitas poderiam ser duplicatas. Por exemplo `if (x = 1)` não é necessariamente erro de digitação, muitas pessoas fazem isto porque não sabem a diferença, mas só precisa de uma pergunta com isto.

Claro, tudo isto é debatível, mas este foi sempre o entendimento. Hoje eu tenho uma visão mais clara sobre o funcionamento do site e acho que muita coisa precisa ser diferente, mas não é só mudar a interpretação, a ferramenta tem que ajudar. Não sei se precisa neste caso. Por isso eu prefiro regras mais rígidas, mesmo que a regra seja "aceita tudo" (não que eu ache certo, mas pelo menos é uma regra mais clara).

Ser um problema específico não é ser um problema individual. Isto quer dizer que não pode ser um programa geral, ou seja, não pode "como faço um relatório de vendas?". Deve ser "por que o total da coluna x está imprimindo asteriscos?".

Já falei antes que eu acho que no fundo o que as pessoas querem é um fórum e me parece que a SE enxergou isso e até [vem tentando fazer isto acontecer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), para o bem ou para o mal. Só acho uma pena terem matado o Docs, deveriam ter melhorado o que estava errado. Ele ajudava o SO virar um fórum porque concentraria informações canônicas deixando o Q&A para algo mais individualizado. Inclusive o individualizado poderia ser o gatilho para algo canônico. E daí poderiam criar roteiros de treinamento no que existe canonicamente. O Docs poderia ter uma característica mais wiki. Hoje eu vejo o Quora mais como um Q&A legítimo do que o SO.

Que venham outras opiniões.